# How to parse data from ViewData

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to parse data from my ViewData but its not going so well.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ListFilm()
        {
            MediaCatalog mediaCL = new MediaCatalog();

            // Retrieve a list of film media's
            List<CatalogDb.FilmMedia> listFilmMedia = new List<CatalogDb.FilmMedia>();
            listFilmMedia = mediaCL.GetAllFilmMediaTitles();

            ViewData["FilmList"] = listFilmMedia.ToList();

            return View();
        }
```

View:

```
<% foreach(var item in (ViewData["FilmList"] as List<CatalogDb.FilmMedia>)) { %>
<%=item.title %>
<% } %>
```

I noticed that the code written in my view file is parsed directly in the source, so for some reason its not being executed as code?

Comment: Personally I like to use ViewBag rather than ViewData since it is strongly typed (it uses the new dynamic feature of .NET 4.0 under the hood).

Comment: @Styxxy, could you give an example? I would love to see how this can be done.

Comment: Instead of `ViewData["MyProperty"]` you do `ViewBag.MyProperty`, that's all; ow yeah, you don't have to cast any more. Note: you need ASP.NET MVC 3 in order to use this.

Comment: That was amazingely simple. Kindly make an answer that i can accept. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use the [`ViewBag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) property, it has been added to ASP.NET MVC3. It uses the [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controllerbase.viewbag%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) under the hood, which makes the `ViewBag` also strongly typed. (`ViewData` uses a dictionary under the hood and thus always returns an object , which you have to cast).

So basically, instead of using `ViewData["MyPropery"] as MyType`, you can directly call `ViewBag.MyProperty` and you don't need to cast it (to "MyType").

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using razor view engine, your syntax is incorrect and your code is not parsed.
In [razor view engine](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/basics/2-introduction-to-asp-net-web-programming-using-the-razor-syntax) you would have to write something like

```
@foreach (var item in (ViewData["FilmList"] as List<CatalogDb.FilmMedia>))
{
 @item.title
}
```

What you've written there is web forms view engine syntax. You could either switch to that view engine or write code in razor syntax for your code to be parsed and executed.

Comment: I am using razor engine. Is it a hassle? I could just change it though?

Comment: @JavaCake its not a hastle you just have to use the correct syntax i mentioned above, to output stuff. The syntax you're using is for web forms engine.

Comment: Thanks Hasan. I have an additional problem. My CatalogDb is a namespace from a *.dbml. Is there a way that i can reference this namespace in my webapplication project?

Comment: `Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'CatalogDb' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`